# Angular2 - npm install didn't find namespace webdriver

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, npm-install

After reinitiating an Angular2 project, I've launch the command npm install and got the following error :

```
node_modules/protractor/built/browser.d.ts(258,37): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'webdriver'
```

Anyone knows where it comes from/ how can I fixed it ?

Thanking you,

Comment: Have you tried deleting the whole node_modules and reinstalling all dependencies? Whats in your package.json?

Comment: Facing same issue since morning !!!

Comment: I have the same error with @types/selenium-webdriver 2.53.37.

Comment: does not happen after "npm install @types/selenium-webdriver@2.53.36", i guess something is broken with 2.53.37

Comment: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/13382 was merged last night. I guess this breaks protractor.

Comment: I've tried deleting node_modules and reinstalling all dependencies. I guess @PhilippAumayr is right about the merge last night (the first time this bug appeared)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Update 21-12-2016: This is fixed as of protractor 4.0.14.

protractor has a dependency on selenium-webdriver:

'@types/selenium-webdriver': '~2.53.31',

unfortunately, https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/13382 was merged yesterday and released as 2.53.37.

Temporary fix : manually installing version 2.53.36 fixes the problem until protractor releases a new version incorporating the changes from the selenium-webdriver package.

```
npm install @types/selenium-webdriver@2.53.36 --save-dev
```

and remove the dev dependency as soon as protractor is fixed.

There is a PR pending in : https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/3848

Comment: thanks for that. Let's hope they get that namespace back quick on track

Comment: Theres a PR on the protractor site incoming: https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/3848

Comment: I changed the version to 2.53.36 but still got this error

Comment: @angrykiwi by now you can update to protractor 4.0.14 it the problem should be solved (remove the @types/selenium-webdriver@2.53.36 depencies from your packages.json)

Comment: wow it works, somebody has to update official angular tutorial files.

Comment: I updated to protractor 4.0.14 and the problem persists.  Also tried installing the types @2.53.36 without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

For those still experiencing issues after upgrading to Protractor 4.0.14, I found that my classes that referenced webdriver now required an import statement:

```
import webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
```

Hope that helps anyone with the same issue.